# How to hide the url of an Iframe in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am developing a React component in which I place an Iframe to insert a Jitsi video conference. But I am requested that the URL of this meeting is hidden.
This is the package I use for the Iframe:

```
import Iframe from 'react-iframe';
```

The code for the Iframe is as follows:

```
<Iframe url={meet.url}
  allow="camera; microphone; fullscreen; display-capture; autoplay"
  className={classes.meetIframe}
/>
```

When inspecting in the console the URL is visible. How can I hide it? Is there a way to make the URL not visible in the console?

Comment: If the intent is for the user's browser to send a request to this URL then there is no way to hide this URL from the user's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to hide it. More importantly, I can't understand any reason why you would want to do that?
What is the objective behind this?

Comment: Thank you. The reason for this is that we want the video conference to be accessible only from our site.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't give enough info but from the sound of it. You need to apply network based & host based firewalls, and implement authentication, authorisation etc.. You can't achieve it like this, because sooner or later people can find the address. Its a bit like saying you can't make a house that no one can see, otherwise how will you access it, but you can make it secure so no one breaks in. Think of it like this, if someone can go to the website, then the front end is going to be public anyway, you can't do anything about that

Comment: The objective is that participants in a video conference cannot access it from outside. Because a specific start time and time limit is set. And we must manage it.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your support. I used a separate component that contains the iframe. Something like an iframe within an iframe. This way I hide the URL, but not completely. I think that's enough

Comment: Your most welcome, I am sorry if I didn't completely get your requirement. Seems like an edge case, but I hope it works out for you